# Background image bottom not working

Tags: html, css, razor, html-table

It's my td tag

```
<td style="width: 90%; background: url(../Images/FTBCImg.jpg) repeat-y; ">
```

I use backround image in this td. It's working ,but the bottom border is not worked

See the problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `td` height is not sufficient to cover up entire background so either use `background-size` property to set background correctly else increase your td's height

[**<strike>Demo 1</strike>**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ebgt/) (Fails To Show Full Background, Like Yours)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ebgt/1/) (We Use `background-size` property to fix it)

OR

We increase `td` height

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ebgt/2/)

Comment: Sorry It's Not working !! I was set the height in td tag.but same problem here

Comment: @RameshRajendran make me a fiddle

Comment: make a demo for me on jsfiddle.net and I'll fix it for you

Comment: @RameshRajendran Check out thee demo

Comment: Hey it's working

  <td style="width: 90%; background: url(../Images/FTBCImg.jpg); background-size: 280px 130px;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;">

Thanks a lot friend !

Comment: @RameshRajendran See the support here http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts , you need to use `CSS2Pie` for supporting new properties, else simply stop supporting older versions

Comment: I think the background-size: 280px 130px; background-repeat: no-repeat; not working in ie7 another part working good ! So ie 7 have a same old problem !

Comment: @RameshRajendran Websites like google are going to stop supporting older versions, you can have conditional IE comments to throw a message to your users to upgrade your browser http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

You must have to give position where to start show position of back ground image. You must have to give background-position also. top / left / right / bottom as per your need.

```
<td style="width: 90%; background: url(../Images/FTBCImg.jpg) repeat-y top left; ">
```

Try above.

Comment: then as mention above you have second problem that image url path not properly set or contain height not properly get by css